# 1999 taho gas engine alternator check

Tags: alternator

Had alternator checked but my negative terminal is loose would that give a false reading .. it's really loose and says the part is bad yet when I drive the vehicle it stays in the middle like normal  any help please

Comment: It sure can, get it repaired.

Answer (score 0):

If the negative terminal is loose, and it opens up while the engine runs, you will not get a charge to the battery, but your instrumentation may show that the alternator is putting out current (running the accessories and the ignition) and that the voltage is OK (because it can regulate the power to the car systems).

Assuming you mean the negative terminal on the battery, clean it up, and tighten it up, or replace it.

If you mean the negative terminal on the alternator, they usually don't have them, and rely on the case of the alternator for the negative to ground connection.

If this doesn't address your question, please include more specifics.